# [Error ORABPEL-10902]: compilation failed XML parsing failed Soa Oracle Bpel

Tags: xsd, wsdl, jdeveloper

I'm trying to compile a BPel process and get this error message :

[Error ORABPEL-10902]: compilation failed
 [Description]: in "bpel.xml", XML parsing failed because "undefined part element.
In WSDL at "file:/D:/jdevstudio10135/jdev/mywork/MyBpel/Getinfo/bpel/Getinfo.wsdl",
 message part element "{http://xmlns.oracle.com/Getinfo}GetinfoRequest" is not defined in any of the schemas.
Please make sure the spelling of the element QName is correct and the WSDL import is complete.
". [Potential fix]: n/a.

WSDL of BPel:

```
<definitions
     name="Getinfo"
     targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Getinfo"
     xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"     
     xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Getinfo"
     xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Getinfo"
     xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/"
                xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Getinfo" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Getinfo">
            <import namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Getinfo" schemaLocation="Getinfo.xsd"/>
            <import namespace="http://my.int.com/tps" schemaLocation="MyService.xsd"/>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="GetinfoRequestMessage">
        <part name="payload" element="client:GetinfoRequest"/>
    </message>
    <message name="GetinfoResponseMessage">
        <part name="payload" element="client:GetinfoResponse"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="Getinfo">
        <operation name="process">
            <input message="client:GetinfoRequestMessage"/> 
            <output message="client:GetinfoResponseMessage"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <plnk:partnerLinkType name="Getinfo">
        <plnk:role name="GetinfoProvider">
            <plnk:portType name="ns1:Getinfo"/>
        </plnk:role>
    </plnk:partnerLinkType>
```

XSD imported :

```
<schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
        targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Getinfo"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <element name="GetinfoRequest">
  <complexType>
   <sequence>
    <element name="inID" type="string" nillable="false"/>
   </sequence>
  </complexType>
 </element>
 <element name="GetinfoResponse">
  <complexType>
   <sequence>
    <element name="Price" type="string"/>
   </sequence>
  </complexType>
 </element>
</schema>
```

I'm using JDev 10.3.5.0

I've looked for this error and any of suggestion found could resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and got it to deploy by splitting the import statements into separate schema tags.